# Macro for formatting before print

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen similar questions to this but haven't found a good answer. I am trying to have a macro run automatically that formats the footer date and font before printing.

This code doesn't work, but is close on the date/font formatting:

```
Sub Fix_Footer_Date()
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&14&""Verdana,Bold" & Format(Now, "mmmm dd, yyyy")
End Sub
```

And something like this will automatically run it before it prints?

```
 Option Explicit
 Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
     Your code here
 End Sub
```

How can I combine these into one that works? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that I **strongly** encourage you to qualify the sheet you wish to operate on versus using `ActiveSheet`, as `ActiveSheet` may not always be the sheet you desire to work with.

Second is, I fixed the syntax to get your Page Footer to work as intended. I simply recorded a macro to get the correct syntax (and adjusted it for your formula).

```
Sub Fix_Footer_Date()

Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet") 'change as needed

ws.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&""Verdana,Bold""&14" & Format(Now, "mmmm dd, yyyy")

End Sub
```

Then, just call the macro in your `Before_Print` event.

```
Option Explicit
 Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
     Fix_Footer_Date 'you could also write the code directly into this event, if you wish.
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Scott. The font/date formatting line still doesn't quite work. The font-family (Verdana) works, but it isn't coming out bold, and the date I'm left with just says "2015" when it should say "December 8, 2015". Any idea?

Comment: @Nick - I think I copied the wrong syntax into my answer the first time. I just edited it with the correct syntax. It's a bit funky and specific, but with macro recorder, I figured it out :)